# Remove from list a range based on an objects properties

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to remove all integers from a list that are greater than 1 but also lower than 10, I end up removing every number below 10 including the required number 1. How could both conditions be satisfied using linq? The code I currently have:

```
availableCards.RemoveAll(x => x.NumericalValue < 10 && x.NumericalValue > 1);
```

Comment: try adding parentaces and see what happens (x.NumericalValue < 10 && x.NumericalValue > 1)

Comment: `var filteredCards = availableCards.Where(x=> x > 1).Where(x => x < 10).ToList();` `availableCards = availableCards.Except(filteredCards);`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, it works fine.

Comment: Proof that your code works: https://ideone.com/YRqZRz

Comment: Thanks all,  my code did work. The issue was the numbers within the list not the code - just couldn't see it with tired eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the linq statement

```
var tempList= from card in availableCards
                where card.NumericalValue <=1 || card.NumericalValue >=10
                    select card;
```